# Move the outer key inward in an association

Tags: associations

I have a list that looks like:

```
{15000001-><|"Loss" -> 2.85396*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.61052*10^10|>,
 15000002 -> <|"Loss" -> 1.25297*10^8, "Exposure" -> 1.57863*10^11|>,
 15000003 -> <|"Loss" -> 2.05979*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.88024*10^10|>}
```

I want to wind up with this:

```
{<|"Event"->15000001,"Loss" -> 2.85396*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.61052*10^10|>,
 <|"Event"->15000002,"Loss" -> 1.25297*10^8, "Exposure" -> 1.57863*10^11|>,
 <|"Event"->15000003,"Loss" -> 2.05979*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.88024*10^10|>}
```

I tried making two lists, one with Keys and one with Values and putting them together, but I couldn't quite get that to work.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Join @@ KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, "Event" -> #]&] /@ (Association /@ lst)
```

> {<|"Event" -> 15000001, "Loss" -> 2.85396*10^8, 
>     "Exposure" -> 6.61052*10^10|>,
>   <|"Event" -> 15000002, 
>     "Loss" -> 1.25297*10^8, 
>     "Exposure" -> 1.57863*10^11|>,
>    <|"Event" -> 15000003, 
>     "Loss" -> 2.05979*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.88024*10^10|>}

Alternatively, use `Replace`:

```
Replace[lst, HoldPattern[a_ -> <|b___|>] :> <|"Event" -> a, b|>, All]
```

> same result

Answer (score 14):

Here's an approach using [`@@@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) (`Apply` at level `{1}`):

```
Prepend[#2, "Event" -> #] & @@@ lst
(* {
    <|"Event" -> 15000001, "Loss" -> 2.85396*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.61052*10^10|>, 
    <|"Event" -> 15000002, "Loss" -> 1.25297*10^8, "Exposure" -> 1.57863*10^11|>,
    <|"Event" -> 15000003, "Loss" -> 2.05979*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.88024*10^10|>
   } *)
```

As noted by @WReach in the comments, we can also use the (undocumented?) fact that associations behave as if they had the `Flat` attribute (meaning that e.g. `<|a->1,<|b->2|>|>` evaluates to `<|a->1,b->2|>`):

```
<| "Event" -> #, #2 |> & @@@ lst
(* same output *)
```

Comment: +1.  Also: `<| "Event" -> #, #2 |> & @@@  lst`

Comment: @WReach Thanks! I've added your solution as an alternative to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Using `keyPush` by [@alancalvitti](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/801/alancalvitti)

```
keyPush[newKey_][<|k_ -> as_Association|>] := Prepend[newKey -> k][as];

keyPush["Event"][Association@#] & /@ lst
```

> {<|"Event" -> 15000001, "Loss" -> 2.85396*10^8,    "Exposure" ->
>   6.61052*10^10|>, <|"Event" -> 15000002,    "Loss" -> 1.25297*10^8,    "Exposure" -> 1.57863*10^11|>, <|"Event" -> 15000003,    "Loss" ->
>   2.05979*10^8, "Exposure" -> 6.88024*10^10|>}